# involutive automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, involutions

Consider first a finite group, $G$, and an involutive automorphism, $s$, such that the automorphism corresponding to $s^2$ is the identity automorphism. Now consider the subgroup $K(s)$ of $G$ such that an element $k$ of $K(s)$ is such that $s(k)=k$ meaning that the involutive automorphism $s$ applied $k$ is fixed (same as identity applied to $k$). Is it possible to prove that $K(s)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ meaning that for any element $g$ of $G$ and $k$ of $K(s)$ then $g.k.g^{-1}$ is a member of $K(s)$ and if so how would one go about proving it? If it is not true then can anyone give a counter example. If it is any easier take the specific example that the automorphism $s$ is the conjugate transform $s.g.s, s=s^{-1}$.
In this case i need to show $s.g.k.g^{-1}.s=g.k.g^{-1}$.

What about the same idea applied to an infinite order group or some Lie group?
Now that i think about it i guess for the finite group conjugate transform example a good place to start may be consider the permutation groups starting with the $6$ elements of $S_3$ and see if it is or is not true .

Comment: The subgroup $K(s)$ is called the *fixed subgroup of $s$*. They've been studied lots. For free groups, for example, it is an old result of Dyer and Scott[1] that if $s$ has finite order then $K(s)$ is a free factor, and in particular $K(s)$ is not normal (in fact it intersects its proper conjugates trivially; it is *malnormal*). [1]J. L. Dyer and G. P. Scott, *Periodic automorphisms of free groups*, Comm. Alg. 3 (1975), 195-201.

Comment: Main reason I was asking is that in the book by Vilenkin vol.I 'Representations of Lie Groups and Special Functions'  page 55 he states "...s defines the homogenous space X=G/K(s) with the motion group G and stabilizer K(s). " So we have a contradiction because X cannot be a factor group unless K(s) is a normal subgroup so we can only conclude his statement is most certainly incorrect since unless K(s) is a normal subgroup then G/K(s) has no meaning.

Comment: You have miss-understood something. The set-up for the quote is, I believe, and action of $G$ on a space $Y$, an element $s\in Y$, and $K(s):=\{g\in G\mid s\cdot g=s\}$. Translating into automorphism-world, we have $G=\operatorname{Aut}(H)$, $s\in H$, and $K(s):=\{\alpha\in G\mid \alpha(s)=s\}\leq\operatorname{Aut}(H)$. That is, $K(s)$ consists of *automorphisms* and not elements. [Note that the $G$ in both your comment and my comment *does not* correspond to the $G$ in the question. Instead, the $H$ in my comment corresponds to the $G$ in the question.] Does that make sense?

Comment: ok thanks for that clarification. I was just notified of another comment just now.I will try to analyze it more. I had already thought soon after posting that the comment '...incorrect ' was not justified in any case since even if K(s) were elements it could be normal in   the particular G he was considering.though not in the most general case. I was going to make a comment to that effect but no need now.

Comment: He specifically states in the 2 sentences just prior and I quote "An automorphism s of G is involutive if s^2 is identity transform of G. To every involutive  automorphism s there corresponds the subgroup K(s) of G consisting of elements fixed by this automorphisms: K(s)={k | s(k)=k}." So that is why i perceived K(s) as elements of a subroup and not automorphisms ?

Comment: He specifically states in the 2 sentences just prior ."An automorphism s of a group G is involutive if s^2 is identity transform. To every involutive automorphism s there corresponds the subgroup K(s) of G consisting of elements fixed : K(s)={k | s(k)=k}" So that is why i perceived K(s) as a subgroup of elements in G and NOT automorphisms ? Yea it is somewhat confusing and ambiguous but i believe the group G is not a group of automorphisms and s is not specifically a part of the group G in question though s(G) is necessarily the group G again?

Comment: sorry for the double writing but it did NOT show my comment prior